# Read XML file classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript

I need to read an XML document with classic ASP.

The XML file looks like:

```
<config>
    ...
    <applications>
        <application id="1" link="http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/what-s-new-in-word-2013-HA102809597.aspx">Word 2013</application>
        <application id="2" link="http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/what-s-new-in-excel-2013-HA102809308.aspx">Excel 2013</application>
        ...
    </applications>
    ...
</config>
```

I want to retrieve all `application` tags and store them into a Dictionnary. The key is the application name and the value is the link attribute.

Here is my code (**corrected with the very good replies I got**):

```
Set xmlObj = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlObj.async = False
xmlObj.load(Server.MapPath("/SomePath/Applications.xml"))

' List of application nodes
Dim xmlApp : Set xmlApp = xmlObj.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/config/applications/application")

' Dictionnary of applications
Dim xmlAppCollection : Set xmlAppCollection = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
' Single application node
Dim app

For Each app In xmlApp
    ' Populate the application dictionnary
    If app.Attributes.GetNamedItem("link") Is Nothing Then
        xmlAppCollection.Add app.Text, ""
    Else
        xmlAppCollection.Add app.Text, app.Attributes.GetNamedItem("link")
    End If
Next

Response.write("Count: "&xmlAppCollection.Count)
```

However, `xmlAppCollection.Count` returns zero.

What do I miss?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Now I've got the following error:
`Object doesn't support this property or method: 'app.Value'`.

The problem comes from `xmlAppCollection.Add app.Value, app.Attributes.GetNamedItem("link")`

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I hope this is the last question. I want to loop over the dictionary:

```
' applications is an array of application names
For Each member In applications
    ' Test that the software exists in the dictionary and the link is not empty
    If xmlAppCollection.Exists(member) = True And xmlAppCollection.Item(member) <> "" Then
        Response.write("<tr><th>Software</th><td><a href='" & xmlAppCollection.Item(member) & "'>" & member & "</a></td></tr>")
    Else
        Response.write("<tr><th>Software</th><td>"&member&"</td></tr>")
    End If
Next
```

But I've got the error message: `Object doesn't support this property or method` on the line `If xmlAppCollection.Exists(member) = True And xmlAppCollection.Item(member) <> "" Then`. It seems to come from the `Item` [property](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_item.asp).

Comment: Re. the last problem: split that line into two to see if the problem comes from `Exists()` or from `Item`. Note that `And` in VBScript does NOT short-circuit (if I remember correctly), so `Item` is called even if `Exists()` returns `false`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Okay I keep in mind the `And` doesn't short-circuit the condition. I've already tried to split the line. And the problem definitely comes from `Item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you should use `app.text` instead than `app.Value`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I've updated my question. Do you have an idea about what is going wrong?

Comment: You keep changing the question adding new stuff - and not marking anything as an answer. You should create new questions.

Comment: Well my subject is about reading XML file with ASP and I am still having trouble with it.

Answer (score 2):

Not shure if i'm right, but the selector should start with / if its root, or // if anywhere, also the DocumentElement part not needed.

so try using

Set xmlApp = xmlObj.SelectNodes("//application")

or

Set xmlApp = xmlObj.SelectNodes("/config/applications/application")

also, add some debog response.write to your for each loop, so during development you can see if it's actually doing anything.

[For ref click here.](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: You must be right. I have a new error: `Object doesn't support this property or method: 'app.Value'`. The problem comes from `xmlAppCollection.Add app.Value, app.Attributes.GetNamedItem("link")`